# Having problem in copying a dictionary to a specified location

Tags: objective-c

I am trying to copy my root dictionary to an already set path by using the following statement:

```
[rootObj writeToFile:writableDBPath atomically:TRUE];
```

But the problem is that it is not able to copy `rootObj` at the specified location.

`rootObj` is a mutable dictionary of capacity 4 with 3 key-value pairs.
`writableDBPath` also has a set value into my iPhone simulator's document folder.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

You should check whether you are allowed to write to that path in the first place. Use `NSFileManager`'s `isWritableFileAtPath:` method for that. If this succeeds, but you still can't write to a file, then maybe your objects are not serializable. From NSDictionary documentation:

> This method recursively validates that
>   all the contained objects are property
>   list objects (instances of NSData,
>   NSDate, NSNumber, NSString, NSArray,
>   or NSDictionary) before writing out
>   the file, and returns NO if all the
>   objects are not property list objects,
>   since the resultant file would not be
>   a valid property list

As a last point, note that in Objective-C, you don't use TRUE, you use `YES` (with `NO` being its counterpart).